# Parse multidimensional, mixed array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I've got the following array (the depth is unknown):

```
array(2) {
  ["index"]=>
  object(stdClass)#17 (11) {
    ["desc"]=>
    string(11) "home"
    ["headline"]=>
    string(8) "products"
    ["teaser"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#18 (1) {
        ["sys"]=>
        object(stdClass)#19 (3) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(22) "EQhfcEesaqn4N7L"
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#20 (1) {
        ["sys"]=>
        object(stdClass)#21 (3) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(21) "egJ3xDTeyq8aKtK"
        }
      }
    }
    ["label1"]=>
    object(stdClass)#28 (1) {
      ["sys"]=>
      object(stdClass)#29 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(22) "cwfyDB3WPwU4son"
      }
    }
    ["metaDescription"]=>
    string(127) "Vestibulum Pharetra Bibendum Inceptos Quam"
    ["metaKeywords"]=>
    string(10) "Vestibulum Pharetra Bibendum Inceptos Quam"
    ["metaTitle"]=>
    string(51) "Lorem Ipsum"
  }
  [...]
}
```

All the "sys" objects need to be replaced by a another array.

So if I knew the maximum depth of the array I could do something like (pseudo code):

```
foreach($array as $entry) {
  if(property_exists($entry, 'sys')) {
    // do stuff
  } else {
    foreach($entry as $sub) {
      if(property_exists($sub, 'sys')) {
        // do stuff
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But because every object can have any number of descendants I think I need a recursive function.

How can I parse this array recursive and replace the sys-objects with another object?

Comment: Have you tried to use [`array_walk_recursive`](http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)?

Comment: How can I use it with a multidimensional array?

Comment: Just read the description of that function

Comment: Is it my mistake or doesn't handle `array_walk_recursive` multidimensional objects? With arrays it works as expected but with objects I have to call it recursive (inside my callback function `if(isObject) array_walk_recursive(...))`

Comment: You're right. `array_walk_recursive` doesn't work with nested objects. So the only way is a recursive function.